# How can I compare elements from a list with elements from a list in another list?

Tags: python-3.x

```
a = ['12','45','23','78','14']
b = [['17', 'aa'], ['14', 'bb'], ['24', 'cc'], ['01', 'dd'], ['45', 'ee'], ['']]
```

How can I get from the list b only the lists with the numbers, which are in the list a (`['14', 'bb']` and `['45', 'ee']`) and join this lists:

```
['14 bb'], ['45 ee']
```

I couldn't do it with a for loop and join...

Comment: Please, add some code to the question and make it clearer. I'm struggling to understand what exactly do you want to get

Comment: Can you add the code you have attempted to solve the problem with, and what isn't working?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['12','45','23','78','14']

b = [['17', 'aa'], ['14', 'bb'], ['24', 'cc'], ['01', 'dd'], ['45', 'ee'], ['']]

ans=[]
for items in b:
    if items[0]  in a:
        ans.append(items)

print(ans)
```

Comment: That is what I need! Thank you very much!

Comment: And if a = [['12', 'xx'], ['45', 'xx'], ['23, 'xx'], ['78', 'xx'], ['14', 'xx']], b ist the same and the same task. result should be the same too : (['14', 'bb'] and ['45', 'ee'])

Comment: If you have a list of list in `a` also, traverse the `a` list also using for loop